# Inconsistent application of draw borders script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script scheduled every evening to look at a number of different sheets and draw borders around any new data entries.

The script works yet is inconsistent. When I check it works completely for some google sheets and partially for others. There are about 10 internal sheets on each google spreadsheet and the borders are drawn in for some and not for others.

I don't understand why it is not running clean.

```
function addBorders() {
  //Access the sheet which contains all the IDs
  var idSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('example');

  //Check for the last row
  var lastRow = 0;
  var currRow = 2;
  //Loop through the sheet and find the last ID available
  while (idSheet.getRange("A" + currRow).getValue() != "")
  {
    currRow = currRow + 1;
  }
  //Set the last row with an ID found to be the lastRow
  lastRow = currRow;
  idSheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Total Rows");
  idSheet.getRange("B2").setValue(lastRow);

  //Loop through the ID sheet to find the ID to make changes to
  for( var y = 2; y < lastRow; y++) 
  { 
    var studentID = idSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(y, 1).getValue();

    //As IDs are take from the ID sheet, open the relevant sheet and run the code below
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(studentID);
    var sheetsCount = ss.getNumSheets();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

    //For each sheet in the individal student spreadsheets, set the borders correctly
    for (var i = 0; i < sheetsCount; i++)
    {
      var sheet = sheets[i]; 
      var range = sheet.getRange(6, 3, 35);
      var values = range.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] });

      //clear previous border
      var selection = sheet.getRange(6,2,35,5)
      selection.setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);  

      //set border
      var index = values.indexOf("");

      var border = sheet.getRange(5, 2, index+1, 5);
      border.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect `while (idSheet.getRange("A" + currRow).getValue() != "")` you must specify a sheet (i.e. tab) example: `idSheet.getRange( "Sheet1!A" + currRow).getValue()!="")` If this works then it's probably always using ss.getSheets()[0] the most left sheet.

This will result in not accessing the data in the last row

```
for( var y = 2; y < lastRow; y++)
```

How do you know that the index below will never be -1.  If it is then index + 1 = 0 which is not a legal row value.  Seems a little flaky to me.

```
var index = values.indexOf("");
var border = sheet.getRange(5, 2, index+1, 5);
```

- [Spreadsheet.getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String))

Comment: OK, I understand the error. The code does pull out the ID's to run the border code on though. There are around 250 ID's to run the border code through and it takes around 20mins to complete. The script log always says there were no errors yet not all the borders are drawn.

Comment: You can check the executions, execution transcript and the stack logger.  If you go to GSuite Developer Hub you can view failed executions also.  Hopefully, one of those locations will have an error report.